# Facebook post on friend wall via iphone app limitations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

i use the following code to post on facebook friend wall invitation for my iphone application

Do I have limitation for number of users i post on their wall daily and do i have limitation for number of posts per user?

I use this code to let my app user invite his friends by posting on their wall

```
 Facebook* facebook =
    [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appID andDelegate:self];


    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
                                   @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                   @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
                                   @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",friendId]
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id     result,NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@", result);
     }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official Limit afaik, but Facebook will definitely limit your app if many users mark your entries as spam or block the app. Which will most likely happen if you post something on the walls of the user´s friends.

Also keep in mind that (thankfully) posting on wall of the user´s friends is a deprecated functionality and will not be available anymore very soon, because in 99% of the cases it´s unwanted and spam. People are very picky with stuff that comes from an app and not from a user directly.

See Roadmap:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

> Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API